# GoDaddy PEM and SPC to PFX for a WinForm Click-Once Installation

Tags: windows, winforms, code-signing, pfx

I am way out of my area of knowledge here, but I'm quite sure the answer must be simple...  I need to make a PFX file to sign a winform program and click-once installation utilizing certificate files received from GoDaddy.

A manager got a Certificate from GoDaddy, and I was given a Zip file that contains a .PEM file and a .SPC file.   In a separate folder, there are 2 text files, generate-csr.txt and generated-private-key.txt.   I don't know exactly what steps he has run.   The GoDaddy documentation indicates to use MMC, but walking through those steps leaves generate a .PFX file option disabled.   Google showed up a number of solutions using OpenSSL.exe that seem to lead to something like:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out name.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -certfile inter.pem

However, I am not familiar enough with the file formats to know what the above parameters are, and what I need do to convert whatever I have into something OpenSSL will understand.

Being new to this, I also don't know which steps have to be performed on the computer where the initial request came from (manager's desktop) and what I can do on the development / build computers.

Thanks in advance for your insights.